# How to create initialiser_list object in C++

Tags: c++, neural-network, initialization, opennn

I have troubles with my C++ code. I am using [OpenNN](https://www.opennn.net/) to buid a Neural Network and I want to use my trained Neural Network (see variable neuralnetwork), to predict the output from a set of features (see variable featureVector). I am trying to call a function which needs a initialiser_list - object as argument. This is the code:

```
float featureVector[1][5] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
Tensor<type, 2> inputs(1, featureLength);
inputs.setValues(featureVector);
neuralnetwork.calculate_outputs(inputs);
```

I get this error message:
neuralnetwork.cpp:141:22: error: reference to type 'const typename internal::Initializer<Tensor<float, 2, 0, long long>, NumDimensions>::InitList' (aka 'const initializer_list<initializer_list>') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'float [1][5]'
TensorBase.h:861:81: note: passing argument to parameter 'vals' here

When I change my code according to an example from OpenNN, it works, but this is not what I want because the feature vector needs to be a variable like above:

```
Tensor<type, 2> inputs(1, featureLength);
inputs.setValues({{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}});
neuralnetwork.calculate_outputs(inputs);
```

I also tried to change featureVector to a list (std::list) but this does not work, to. I know that featureVector needs to be an initialiser_list object, but I could not find any answers online on how to initialise an initialiser_list-object. It would be nice if featureVector is a array or std::list, which will be converted to a initialiser_list.

Edit:

Type of neuralnetwork:

```
 OpenNN::NeuralNetwork neuralnetwork;
```

Function calculate_outputs:

```
Tensor<type, 2> NeuralNetwork::calculate_outputs(const Tensor<type, 2>& inputs)
```

With the solution in the comment I figured something out that works for me:

```
auto featureVector1 = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f, 5.f};
auto featureVector = {featureVector1};
Tensor<type, 2> inputs(1, featureLength);
inputs.setValues(featureVector);
neuralnetwork.calculate_outputs(inputs);
```

It does not look nice and maybe it is not perfect, but it this is exactly how I wanted it. Thank you!

Comment: what is the signature of `calculate_outputs`, what type is `neuralnetwork`? Initializer lists are typically created on the fly, maybe you just need to add brackets

Comment: Use OpenNN's `Vector` and `Matrix` types instead of arrays or the standard library's collections.

Comment: For a simple initializer list, `auto initialize_list = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f, 5.f };` That will define the `initializer_list` variable as a `std::initializer_list<float>`. If you want an initializer lists of initializer lists you must be explicit with the type `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>`

Answer (score 0):

> How to create initialiser_list object in C++

You use a braced-init-list. Like in the example that you quote.

> but this is not what I want

Then it seems like `std::initialiser_list` is not a good choice for you. You should try to use something else. Have you checked whether the class has some other member functions?

> the feature vector needs to be a variable like above

The feature vector in your example isn't variable. It's a constant array.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in openNN source what arg types availible to use in setValues() function. I`m not find strictly setValues() but [here](https://www.opennn.net/documentation/reference/tensor_8h_source.html) this code:

```
// Constructors
explicit Tensor(const Vector<size_t>&);
explicit Tensor(const Matrix<T>&);
///....
void set(const Vector<size_t>&);
void set(const Tensor<T>&);
```

So this mean u can create varaible like
`Vector<5> featureVector = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};` or maybe if T  float allowed
`Matrix<float> featureVector = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};`

Or u can create Tensor object and pass in constructor `Vector` or `Matrix` object without using set. Note that this `Vector` is not the same as `std::vector`, it`s the difend in openNN lib data structure.