# Pass List to Function Requiring std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list< type > >?

Tags: c++, list, eigen, eigen3, opennn

I'm using OpenNN to write a proof of concept right now, and I'm having an issue with declaring inputs for a Tensor.

From the OpenNN [website](https://www.opennn.net/documentation/classification_example.html) we see that the neural net accepts a Tensor input

```
Tensor<type, 2> inputs(1,9);
inputs.setValues({{type(4),type(3),type(3),type(2),type(3),type(4),type(3),type(2),type(1)}});
neural_network.calculate_outputs(inputs);
```

I did figure out a workaround to convert a vector to a tensor, but it's long and a little tedious.

I then attempted to pass a vector of a vector, a brace enclosed vector, a brace enclosed array, a dynamically allocated array of the list of values.

The error:

```
cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const Eigen::internal::Initializer<Eigen::Tensor<long long unsigned int, 2>, 2>::InitList&' {aka 'const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<long long unsigned int> >&'}
```

The error continues to just be a variation of (Type does not match type)
The code to reproduce the error (assuming you've gotten the OpenNN library setup.

```
Tensor<uint64_t, 2> createFilledTensor(int index)
{ 
   uint64_t * inList = new uint64_t[index]();
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        inList[i] = 356534563546356;
    }

    Tensor<uint64_t, 2> inputs(1, index);

    inputs.setValues({inList});
    return inputs;
}
```

Also, feel it's worth noting, right now the data doesn't matter as I am trying to figure out HOW to get it to the tensor.

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour] that was offered when you signed up with Stack Overflow as well as reading [ask] and the [Asking Questions portion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get some tips on how to use the site.

Comment: Lacks a [mre], making it less accessible to future askers with a similar problem.

Comment: A MRE is something that anyone can drop into their tools and, assuming they have Eigen and friends installed, compile and see exactly what you are seeing (within the vagaries of any undefined behaviour in the code - not an issue in your case). Wrapping that final snippet up into a complete compliable function is about all you should need. Agree that data's not an issue here since you're struggling with a compile time problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm being honest, that is incredibly pretentious but if it satisfies you, it's in a function next time you reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Found a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67585636/how-to-create-initialiser-list-object-in-c?rq=1)

This solution is more for anyone else that comes around and my question can't be answered;

I solved this problem as follows:

```
namespace Eigen {
  template < typename T >
  decltype(auto) TensorLayoutSwap(T&& t)
  {
    return Eigen::TensorLayoutSwapOp<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(t);
  }
}

Eigen::Tensor<uint64_t, 2> createDataSetFromPair(std::pair<std::vector<uint64_t>, int> data)
{
    Eigen::Tensor<uint64_t, 2> dataTensor(1,data.second);
    auto mapped_t = Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<uint64_t, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>>(&(data.first)[0], data.first.size(), 1);

    return Eigen::TensorLayoutSwap(mapped_t);
}
```

where pair(vec is the data list, and int is the amount of data being processed. I did this for my personal use as it has special application for what I'm doing, but I believe you could use vec.size() and only need a vector as a param